# How do I convert a dataframe to a dictionary with keys that are lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
uniprot_id  GO_id
11  A0A009KHZ9  GO:0006097
12  A0A009KHZ9  GO:0006099
16  A0A009KHZ9  GO:0006099
17  A0A009KJV3  GO:0006412
20  A0A009KJV3  GO:0006417
27  A0A009KJV3  GO:0006412
28  A0A009KXK5  GO:0022900
41  A0A009KXK5  GO:0006457
43  A0A009LQ34  GO:0046690
49  A0A009YU38  GO:0015074
```

`print(len(df))` has over 50 million rows

As you can see, uniprot_id has duplicates.

I want to make a dictionary that has uniprot_id as the key and GO_id as a value. When there are multiple rows for a uniprot_id, I want to make a dictionary that has a list of GO_ids as a value. For example, `A0A009KHZ9` would look like this:

```
{'A0A009KHZ9': [GO:0006097, GO:0006099, GO:0006099]}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
results = {} 
for k in df['uniprot_id']:
  for v in df['GO_id']:
    results.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

results
```

But this results in a dictionary that appends all values to each key (I tested this on a smaller dataframe).

I also tried this:

```
results = {}                              
for k, v in df.set_index('uniprot_id'):                    
    results.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

But I get this error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `groupby()` ,`agg()` and `to_dict()` method:

```
dct=df.groupby('uniprot_id')['GO_id'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

output of `dct`:

```
{'A0A009KHZ9': ['GO:0006097', 'GO:0006099', 'GO:0006099'],
 'A0A009KJV3': ['GO:0006412', 'GO:0006417', 'GO:0006412'],
 'A0A009KXK5': ['GO:0022900', 'GO:0006457'],
 'A0A009LQ34': ['GO:0046690'],
 'A0A009YU38': ['GO:0015074']}
```